# how does a network provider send OTA settings for GPRS/MMS activation

Tags: settings, ota

Thanks for help in advance..

How does a mobile network provider send the OTA settings for GPRS/MMS activation to a GPRS/MMS compatible mobile handset?
Can anyone please provide the steps/procedure followed for it? Is there any documentation published over the web?

Answer (score 2):

It is done by means of OMA OTA(Opne Mobile Alliance OTA) Setting SMS/WAP XML. 
It can be a special kind of SMS which is known by OTA compatible devices. A list of these kind of messages can be found [here.](http://www.routomessaging.com/message-sms-types.pmx)